# UrlParameter is always null in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I cannot get the UrlParameter's value in MVC. I think everything is setup correctly except 1 thing.

here is my MapRoute

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Banyo", // name it!
          "{controller}/{action}/{Filtre}", // Route name
           new { controller = "Banyo", action = "Marka", Filtre = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Home", // Route name
            "{action}/{Filtre}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", Filtre = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

and here is the Action function...

```
public ActionResult Marka(string Filtre = null)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and Filtre returns always null even I enter the url "http://localhost:7555/Banyo/Marka/Seranit" . I was expecting to get "Seranit" value Filtre parameter.

if I enter "localhost:7555/Banyo/Marka?Filtre=Seranit"; ... Filtre paramter gives me the value "Seranit" as expected. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied your route configuration and created a controller just like you did and it worked. Do you have a default route? is it defined before the custom route? take into account that the default route will catch it first if it is defined before. Let me know so I can help you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time. As I copied my routes up, there are only two routes and the custom one is above the default one. And now I commented out the default one. it still behaves the same way

Comment: That's weird, I just copied and pasted everything and it worked. Please, create an empty project and copy and paste your code there.

Comment: I just created a new mvc project and copied but it behaves the same way :( would you please send me your sample project???

Comment: Keep only the custom route for testing purposes.

Comment: yeah, I just added the custom one.... but If I enter "localhost:7555/Banyo/Marka?Filtre=Seranit", then Filtre parameter gives me the value. I dont understand why it behaves like that

Comment: The weirdest thing is that it works on my computer copying and pasting your code. Are you sure the port number is fine? I mean, you are calling localhost:7555 and maybe the changes are being deployed on a different port. Confirm that, please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76739/discussion-between-arif-yilmaz-and-francisco-goldenstein).